# In Flutter the keyboard closes after being opened by clicking on the textfield of the dialogue box

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### How can I resolve this problem?.

The keyboard closes after being opened by clicking on the textfield of the dialogue box..

Actually, I want to set the valid text length to 10, but when I click on the text field, it automatically unfocuse.

I have used a code for doing this has been mentioned below.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:bonanza_flutter/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/UIs/Dashboard/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddNewMemberPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AddNewMemberPage> createState() => _AddNewMemberPageState();
}

class _AddNewMemberPageState extends State<AddNewMemberPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: dialogContent(context),
    );
  }
}

double t4Size = 14;

extension widgetExtension on _AddNewMemberPageState {

  dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
    TextEditingController addPanController = TextEditingController();
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.3, sigmaY: 3.3),
        child: Dialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
          shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
          // backgroundColor: skyBlue,
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    offset: const Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Add New Member",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: tSize26,
                        color: skyBlue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [

                        Padding(
                          padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 4,top: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "PAN Card",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: tSize14,
                              color: darkGreyColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              if (value.length == 10) {
                                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                              }

                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.length == 10) {
                                return null;
                              }
                              return "";
                            },
                            maxLength: 10,

                            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                            controller: addPanController,
                            cursorColor: Theme.of(context).cursorColor,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              counterText: "",
                              hintText: "Enter PAN number",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: greyColor),
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                                borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: mediumGreyColor, width: 1.7),
                              ),
                              contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 12),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: mediumGreyColor, width: 1.7),
                              ),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.verified_user_rounded,
                                color: greyColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Note: PAN number should be connected to same phone number by which you currently sign in.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: tSize14,
                        color: greyColor,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 00.0, bottom: 4, left: 30, right: 30),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 45,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: skyBlue, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              (MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Dashboard())));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Add Member',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: tSize16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my on click fuction

```
             showDialog(
                  useRootNavigator: true,
                  barrierDismissible: false,
                  barrierColor: skyBlue.withOpacity(0.4),
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AddNewMemberPage();
                  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I discovered an issue with your _formKey.**

Use the below code to fix your issue :

```
class AddNewMemberPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewMemberPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddNewMemberPage> createState() => _AddNewMemberPageState();
}

class _AddNewMemberPageState extends State<AddNewMemberPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: dialogContent(
        context,
        _formKey,
      ),
    );
  }
}

double t4Size = 14;

dialogContent(BuildContext context, GlobalKey _key) {
  TextEditingController addPanController = TextEditingController();
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.3, sigmaY: 3.3),
      child: Dialog(
        insetPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        // backgroundColor: skyBlue,
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Add New Member",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _key,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 4, top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "PAN Card",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            if (value.length == 10) {
                              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                            }
                          },
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.length == 10) {
                              return null;
                            }
                            return "";
                          },
                          maxLength: 10,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                          controller: addPanController,
                          cursorColor: Theme.of(context).cursorColor,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            counterText: "",
                            hintText: "Enter PAN number",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 12),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.verified_user_rounded,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Note: PAN number should be connected to same phone number by which you currently sign in.",
                    style: TextStyle(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 00.0, bottom: 4, left: 30, right: 30),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 45,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add Member',
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```